# How to input values or phrases on a window?

Tags: java, string, console, rendering, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that solves an equation for a school project, but I can't figure out how to create a space for writing in the screen instead of eclipse's console. Like, creating a space in the bottom of the window so the user can input the requested values and the program can read that and make the equation, finally showing the user the final result.

```
public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    
    public static JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private final int WIDTH = 160;
    private final int HEIGHT = 120;
    private final int SCALE = 4;
    
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    public Main() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        initFrame();
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        }
    
    public void initFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Tempo de Queda (Física)");
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        isRunning = true;
        thread.start();
    }
    
    public synchronized void stop() {
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
        Main main = new Main();
        
        main.start();}
    
    public void tick() {
        
    }
    
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        //Back Ground---------------------------------------
        g.setColor(new Color(19,19,19));
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,null);
        //Back Ground---------------------------------------
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20));
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawString("Write Here: ", 5,20);
        bs.show();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        long lastTime  = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(isRunning) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+= (now-lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                render();
                frames++;
                delta--;
            }
            
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) {
                System.out.println("FPS: "+frames);
                frames = 0;
                timer+=1000;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, I'd make some additions to the `initFrame` method.  Specifically, you'll want to `add` a `JPanel` to it.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
```

Then, define your `JTextField`s, a `JButton` and any `JLabel`s to go with them.  Java will want you to define any that you're messing with the text value as "final."  The other components are ok to set as "final" if you don't plan on reinitializing them:

```
final JLabel labelX = new JLabel();
final JLabel labelY = new JLabel();
final JLabel output = new JLabel();
final JTextField inputX = new JTextField(5);
final JTextField inputY = new JTextField(5);
final JButton button = new JButton("multiply");
```

Setting the text of any labels is a good idea:

```
labelX.setText("X");
labelY.setText("Y");
output.setText("NaN");
```

Then add them all to the `panel`:

```
panel.add(labelX);
panel.add(inputX);
panel.add(labelY);
panel.add(inputY);
panel.add(button);
panel.add(output);
```

Finally, you'll need to add a listener for the button action.  This is where you'll process your inputs and display the output.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        float valueX = 0;
        float valueY = 0;
        boolean validInputs = true;
            
        try {
            valueX = Float.parseFloat(inputX.getText());
            valueY = Float.parseFloat(inputY.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            output.setText("Invalid input value(s)");
            validInputs = false;
        }
        
        if (validInputs) {
        //multiply
            float result = valueX * valueY;
            output.setText(Float.toString(result));             
        }
    }
});
```

Running that should give you something like this:

[image]

Link to Github: [FloatMathGUI](https://github.com/aploetz/floatMathGUI/blob/main/src/main/java/floatMathGUI/FloatMathGUI.java)

Comment: Thank you, I might take some time to figure this out because I'm new in coding but I'm sure this will help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I tried it here and for some reason it says this "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JFrame.add(java.awt.Component)" because "tempoQueda.Main.frame" is null
, tempoQueda is the name of the program. I tried taking off the whole JFrame setting but that didn't help.

Comment: @DanielBrossmannMuller It sounds like the JFrame isn't getting initialized before use.  Maybe call the `initFrame()` method earlier?

Comment: @DanielBrossmannMuller posted a link to my Git repo.  Hope this helps!